# How to get XML file from Java Request object before sending. Web services SOAP

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am building `Java` application for `Online Web Services` and let's call it `application A` . I got the `WSDL` file form the second party so I can communicate with their application and let's call it `application B`.

From the `WSDL` file I generate the `Java` classes needed which are `Requests` and `Responses` classes. `Application A` will send some `request` object after setting the needed parameters and excepting `response` object from `application B`.

The connection is established and both `applications A and B` are communicating with each other.

**Question:**

From `application A` how can I get the `xml` data(file or text) for the `request` object before sending it to `application B`?

As described the connection is done by passing `Java` object as `request` and I know that in some point this `request` will be converted to `xml` file. How to get it?

**--- EDIT ----**

Important Information is missing that may cause confusion.

I am generated the `Java` Classed have been generated using `Axis` framework

Comment: For testing and getting sample message use SOAP UI utility. Very easy. Will do what you need in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding the following statements in the `bindingStub` class that has been auto generated from the `WSDL` file for the `web-services` you are trying to access.

```
String request = _call.getMessageContext().getRequestMessage().getSOAPPartAsString();
String response = _call.getMessageContext().getResponseMessage().getSOAPPartAsString();
```

These statements should be placed after the following method call `_call.invoke` otherwise you will get `NullPointerException` .

`_call` is a variable of type  `org.apache.axis.client.Cal` and it is auto generated by `Axis`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much reputation to post a comment, so here is my answer: If you aren't yet using some framework use [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), If you want to capture the request before sending it application , you can either use [cxf interceptors](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) there are some inbuilt interceptors which can do this or you can create a custom interceptor with correct phase ( e.g. post marshal)

Comment: Yeah Apache CXF is a great tools for this programming problem. Good suggestion.

Comment: @Namphibian @Raul Actuality, I do not have enough knowledge in `Apache CXF` and it the time is essential in my case. any other suggestion will be appreciated. Every thing is working fine in the application, the `xml`file for the request is for testing and monitoring purpose and it is not important for the programming, but important for testing.